# How to make custom Cards Against Humanity Cards?

Tags: custom-game-pieces, print-and-play, cards-against-humanity

Cards Against Humanity has a free download for a PDF to print custom cards (e.g. [PDF for printing custom white cards](http://s3.amazonaws.com/cah/CAH_BlankWhiteCards.pdf)). However, it seems that these cards are not the same shape/size as the official cards which you get when you purchase the game. The reason for this, clearly, is that while the game is offered via a creative commons-type license, so you can print your own, they want to differentiate their own version.

However, I want to print custom cards which can be used alongside the 'official' version which I own. For this to work, they need to look exactly like the other cards - at least in shape, color, card stock, and finish. That way, when such cards are mixed into the deck and we are playing, it isn't possible to tell when someone has a 'custom' card or an 'official' one.

So my question is, how should I go about printing such customer cards?

If I want to print custom cards which fit in with the regular cards which you can purchase, what card stock should I use to print them with the appropriate weight, glossy surface, etc? I have experience printing a magazine and would be happy to go to either a Kinkos or small-scale printer.

Comment: I think this will be very difficult or impossible to mix print-and-play with the official version. However, you could go all print-and-play, printing a base set as well as whatever blank cards you'd like.

Comment: This page might be very helpful :)
http://biggerblackercards.com/

Answer (score 6):

*A simple solution if you are willing and able to spend some money:*

Buy another copy of the game, a foam paint brush, and a small container of white paint. Using the foam brush you can paint a nice, even, thin coat of white paint over the face of the cards and use a black permanent marker when they dry to write whatever your heart desires!

Answer (score 6):

Crabs Adjust Humidity is a 3rd party expansion pack, they offer packs of just blank cards which are almost identical to the original cards if you don't have enough blank cards in the expansions to write your own cards on. I have ordered about 8 of these now and just keep on expanding my own deck.

Answer (score 2):

Could you not use a standard deck of cards, paste paper printouts on them, and then sleeve *all* the cards?

Comment: CAH cards are different dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

I created templates for printing on the 'Spare cards' that come with the expansion packs.
I then bought Avery Crystal Clear labels (L7784)and used a laser printer to print them out. I cut them to size then applied them to the blanks and they look and feel almost identical to the Originals.

Answer (score 2):

Expansion packs 1-4 each include blank cards - 8 white cards and 4 black cards. The Bigger Blacker Box expansion (and box) contains 50 blank cards (10 black and 40 white). These blanks printed using the exact same process as all the other CAH cards, so they're virtually indistinguishable from the official cards. With a blank card, you just write on it with a marker (Sharpie) and you're done; just be sure to print nicely.

Also note that if you're going to "erase" cards for re-purposing, the expansions are quite a bit cheaper than the full game.

Comment: Their updated product range include a box of just blank cards... It might be possible to print on them, but some experimentation to find suitable ink / toner might be needed....

Answer (score 1):

There's a website for making your own, generating a PDF, sharing, and printing your own cards. Unaffiliated with CAH or Apples to Apples, but quite similar and easier than hand-writing or editing a PDF.

[Snubs-n-dunk](http://snubsndunk.com)

Answer (score 1):

A cheaper suggestion is this: buy a set of [card sleeves with one opaque face](http://blogs.magicjudges.org/rulestips/2011/10/what-opaque-sleeves-are/), print your cards and sleeve both your set and the original set. No one will know what they might draw. There are many options being sold in [Amazon.com](http://www.amazon.com/b?ie=UTF8&node=2358925011) and in many other game stores.

You may want to [know more about the quality of those sleeves](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1742/what-factors-should-i-consider-when-choosing-card-sleeves) prior to buying.

Answer (score 1):

You could always buy a pack of blank cards and then use Moo.com to create custom stickers to stick on the blank side. It would be virtually impossible to tell the difference unless you really disturb your cards

Comment: I substituted "disturb" for "molest," which is a bad word in English.

Comment: @TomAu: I think "molest" is an appropriate, if somewhat colorful, expression here. Certainly it fits better than "disturb". If you wanted a better neutral synonym, "mistreat" / "mishandle" might work.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: In the United States, it is not illegal to "disturb" (e.g. to wake or annoy) children, but it is illegal to "molest" them (as the term is generally understood).

Comment: @TomAu: Yes, you seem to understand the meaning of those words correctly, at least as applied to people. It's not common to use "disturb" for inanimate objects like cards, though, except in the sense of "disturbing [the position/order of] the cards" e.g. by slightly moving them, which the OP does not seem to mean. For the presumably intended sense of "severely abuse and damage", the verb "molest" seems quite appropriate.

Comment: 'deface' might be a better word than disturb.